# Use lmodern package for minted code and palatino package for the rest of the report

Tags: fonts, pdftex, minted, code

I am writing a technical report and I need to use the `palatino` package for it. However, the `minted` code font is not very legible since it doesn't use deep black but slight gray instead. Hence I want to use `lmodern` package for the bold typewriter font for `minted`. How can I use two different fonts in the same report?

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino} % default font for report
% \usepackage{lmodern} % Allows bold typewriter font

\usepackage[chapter]{minted} % (recommended)
% Set global Minted options
\setminted{linenos, autogobble, breaklines, frame=lines, fontsize=\normalsize, framesep=2mm}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the font for the listings with Latin Modern Typewriter in the “light” variant.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{palatino}% sure?
\usepackage[chapter]{minted} % (recommended)

% Set global Minted options
\setminted{
  linenos,
  autogobble,
  breaklines,
  frame=lines,
  fontsize=\normalsize,
  framesep=2mm,
}

% monospaced font is Latin Modern Typewriter Light
\makeatletter
\let\lmtt@use@light@as@normal\@empty
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}

\begin{document}

Some text in Palatino.

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't enable the light variant, you'd get

[image]

where boldface is not really distinguishable.

For comparison, this is the default when using `palatino`.

[image]

Another possibility is Bera Mono

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{palatino}% sure?
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted} % (recommended)

% Set global Minted options
\setminted{
  linenos,
  autogobble,
  breaklines,
  frame=lines,
  fontsize=\fontencoding{T1}\normalsize,
  framesep=2mm,
}

\begin{document}

Some text in Palatino.

\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]